# How to append shadow effect to imageview in android?

Tags: android, uiimageview, shadow, effect

I want to show imageview like 3d image with shadow effect please help me

Answer (score 2):

Create one xml layout file under res -> drawable folder. Lets name it "image_shadow.xml", then copy below code to it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item >
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray" />
        <corners android:radius="0dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>
<item android:right="1dp"  android:bottom="2dp">
    <shape
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
        <corners android:radius="1dp"/>
    </shape>
</item>

</layer-list>
```

And then apply it within your `ImageView` as

```
android:background="@drawable/image_shadow
```

Hope it might help you.

Comment: Happy to help always. please accept my answer if it was helpful to you!